# Binary Image Orientation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to find the orientation of a binary image (where orientation is defined to be the axis of least moment of inertia, i.e. least second moment of area). I'm using Dr. Horn's book (MIT) on Robot Vision [which can be found here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/courses/papers/RoVis/ch3_BI_geometric.pdf) as reference.

Using OpenCV, here is my function, where a, b, and c are the second moments of area as found on page 15 of the pdf above (page 60 of the text):

```
Point3d findCenterAndOrientation(const Mat& src)
{
    Moments m = cv::moments(src, true);
    double cen_x = m.m10/m.m00; //Centers are right
    double cen_y = m.m01/m.m00;

    double a = m.m20-m.m00*cen_x*cen_x;
    double b = 2*m.m11-m.m00*(cen_x*cen_x+cen_y*cen_y);
    double c = m.m02-m.m00*cen_y*cen_y;

    double theta = a==c?0:atan2(b, a-c)/2.0;

    return Point3d(cen_x, cen_y, theta);
}
```

OpenCV calculates the second moments around the origin (0,0) so I have to use the [Parallel Axis Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) to move the axis to the center of the shape, mr^2.

The center looks right when I call

```
Point3d p = findCenterAndOrientation(src);
rectangle(src, Point(p.x-1,p.y-1), Point(p.x+1, p.y+1), Scalar(0.25), 1);
```

But when I try to draw the axis with lowest moment of inertia, using this function, it looks completely **wrong**:

```
line(src, (Point(p.x,p.y)-Point(100*cos(p.z), 100*sin(p.z))), (Point(p.x, p.y)+Point(100*cos(p.z), 100*sin(p.z))), Scalar(0.5), 1);
```

Here are some examples of input and output:

[image]
[image]

(I'd expect it to be vertical)

[image]
[image]

(I'd expect it to be horizontal)

Comment: What are the values for a, b and c - and theta? Could you print those out and convince yourself they are right? What happens when you center the object? Does that help? Those would be two debugging steps to get started...

Comment: For a starting point, you should be dividing like `m20/m00` and not subtracting.

Comment: the m.m00 part on a,b,c etc. is using the parallel axis theorem to move the point of rotation from the image origin to the object origin.

Comment: @Jason only the /central/ moments are calculated taking into consideration the centroid, the second moments `m20` and etc are not /central/ moments, thus they are not calculated "around the origin (0, 0)" (but `mu20` and etc are). There is no parallel axis theorem to be applied here.

Comment: I think this can be solved using 'deskew using opencv moments'  as http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/ and http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked with the orientation sometimes back and coded the following. It returns me the exact orientation of the object. largest_contour is the shape that is detected.

```
CvMoments moments1,cenmoments1;
           double M00, M01, M10;

           cvMoments(largest_contour,&moments1);
           M00 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments1,0,0);
           M10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments1,1,0);
           M01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(&moments1,0,1);
           posX_Yellow = (int)(M10/M00);
           posY_Yellow = (int)(M01/M00);

          double theta = 0.5 * atan(
                    (2 * cvGetCentralMoment(&moments1, 1, 1)) /
                    (cvGetCentralMoment(&moments1, 2, 0) -  cvGetCentralMoment(&moments1, 0, 2)));
                theta = (theta / PI) * 180;

                // fit an ellipse (and draw it)

                if (largest_contour->total >= 6) // can only do an ellipse fit
                                                 // if we have > 6 points
                {
                    CvBox2D box = cvFitEllipse2(largest_contour);
                    if ((box.size.width < imgYellowThresh->width) &&  (box.size.height < imgYellowThresh->height))
                    {

                        cvEllipseBox(imgYellowThresh, box, CV_RGB(255, 255 ,255), 3, 8, 0 );
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Just changed the a,b, & c to the central moments. Thanks!

Comment: So why don't you just use the center point and angle from your `box` then? All the moments calculations you do is not used... and same as center point and angle of `box` (RotatedRectangle in C++)