# Orientation of non symmetrical a shape in Emgu or OpenCv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, shapes, emgucv

I'm trying to obtain the orientation of a shape (binary or contour). The shape is mostly rectangular but has a large hole on one side. I want my orientation to be consistent with this assymetry in the object.

I've been looking at several articles that use the spatial and central moments for this. E.g. 
[Binary Image Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720722/binary-image-orientation)
but it seems that the orientation I get with this is sometimes off with a multiple of 90 degrees.

The following document states that there is some ambiguity:
http://public.cranfield.ac.uk/c5354/teaching/dip/opencv/SimpleImageAnalysisbyMoments.pdf

If I implement this using

```
private void GetCenterAndOrientationViaMoments(Contour<Point> cont, Size imageSize)
{
    // obtain the orientation of the found object
    // first draw the binary blob in a separate image 
    // I do this for the hole(s) in the image, but I'm not sure if it is needed. 
    // Possibly I can tak the moments directly from the contour
    Image<Gray, byte> instanceImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(imageSize);
    instanceImage.FillConvexPoly(cont.ToArray(), new Gray(255));
    for (Contour<Point> hole = cont.VNext;
        hole != null;
        hole = hole.HNext)
            instanceImage.FillConvexPoly(hole.ToArray(), new Gray(0));

    // calculate the moments
    MCvMoments m = instanceImage.GetMoments(true);
//  MCvMoments m = cont.GetMoments();

    double m00 = m.GetSpatialMoment(0, 0);
    double m10 = m.GetSpatialMoment(1, 0);
    double m01 = m.GetSpatialMoment(0, 1);

    double mu11 = m.GetCentralMoment(1, 1);
    double mu20 = m.GetCentralMoment(2, 0);
    double mu02 = m.GetCentralMoment(0, 2);

    // calculate the center
    PointF center = new PointF((float)(m10 / m00), (float)(m01 / m00));

    // calculate the orientation
    // http://public.cranfield.ac.uk/c5354/teaching/dip/opencv/SimpleImageAnalysisbyMoments.pdf
    double theta = 0;
    double mu20_mu02 = (mu20 - mu02);
    if ((mu20_mu02 == 0) & (mu11 == 0))
        theta = 0;
    else if ((mu20_mu02 == 0) & (mu11 > 0))
        theta = Math.PI / 4;
    else if ((mu20_mu02 == 0) & (mu11 < 0))
        theta = -Math.PI / 4;
    else if ((mu20_mu02 > 0) & (mu11 == 0))
        theta = 0;
    else if ((mu20_mu02 < 0) & (mu11 == 0))
        theta = -Math.PI / 2;
    else if ((mu20_mu02 > 0) & (mu11 > 0))
        theta = 0.5 * Math.Atan((2 * mu11) / mu20_mu02);
    else if ((mu20_mu02 > 0) & (mu11 < 0))
        theta = 0.5 * Math.Atan((2 * mu11) / mu20_mu02);
    else if ((mu20_mu02 < 0) & (mu11 > 0))
        theta = 0.5 * Math.Atan((2 * mu11) / mu20_mu02) + Math.PI / 2;
    else if ((mu20_mu02 < 0) & (mu11 < 0))
        theta = 0.5 * Math.Atan((2 * mu11) / mu20_mu02) - Math.PI / 2;

#if DEBUG
    int radius = 25;
    instanceImage.Draw(new CircleF(center, radius), new Gray(100), 2);
    instanceImage.Draw(
        new LineSegment2DF(
            center, 
            new PointF(
                (float)(center.X + radius * Math.Cos(theta)), 
                (float)(center.Y + radius * Math.Sin(theta)))), 
        new Gray(100), 
        2);
    ImageViewer.Show(instanceImage, string.Format("Center and orientation"));
#endif
}
```

My orientation is correct, but does not always point to the same end of the object. In other words, I'm sometimes of by 180 degrees.

I'm guessing the method cannot provide exactly what I want because it uses the covariance of the distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moments#Examples_2) which gives does not take into account the assymmetry caused by the hole, am I right?

Is there a way to resolve the 180 degrees ambiguity?

Regards,
Tom