# Why the OpenCV's fitLine2D_wods is coded like this?

Tags: opencv, least-squares

When I was reading the code: [fitLine2D_wods](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/imgproc/src/linefit.cpp#L92)

```
    t = (float) atan2( 2 * dxy, dx2 - dy2 ) / 2;
    line[0] = (float) cos( t );
    line[1] = (float) sin( t );
```

I cannot get the idea of the statement: `t = (float) atan2( 2 * dxy, dx2 - dy2 ) / 2;`

Could you please help explain it?

I thought it should be this

https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/least-squares-regression.html

I tried to search it on the whole website, but there isn't useful information.

Answer (score 0):

It is the formula of direction(angle) of "Inertia principal axis (? Sorry, I don't know how to say this word in English)" .

Related:
[Binary Image Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720722/)

Comment: I'm hoping someone will correct the word correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found it in OpenCV's API: `cv::moments`